# Problemas com o pacote geobr do R

Tags: r

Utilizo o pacote `geobr` para fazer mapas. Porém, de uns dias para cá, toda vez que venho elaborando o mapa do Brasil com todos os municípios, o mapa não completa e fica igual o mapa abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código, bem simples, seria esse aqui:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(geobr)

ggplot(final) +
 aes(group = name_muni) +
 geom_sf(size = 1L) +
 theme_minimal()
```

Alguém passa pelo mesmo problema?

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la, pois não temos acesso ao objeto `final`. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que os municípios que não estão no mapa estão de fora do `data.frame` usado para criar o mapa (`final`). Eu arriscaria que isso foi resultado de um `left_join` de uma tabela (à esquerda) que tinha dados de apenas alguns municípios.

O código abaixo demonstra como a coisa funciona. Primeiro criemos uma mapa com todos os municípios das UFs de código 11, 12 e 13.

```
library(geobr)
library(tidyverse)
munic <- geobr::read_municipality()
ufs <- munic %>% filter(str_sub(code_state, 1, 2) %in% 11:13)

ggplot(ufs, aes(group = name_muni)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois então, criemos um vetor de 40 municípios que serão removidos do mapa, apenas para mostrar que este é o caso.

```
set.seed(123)
apagar <- ufs$code_muni %>% 
  sample(40)

ufs_sem_muns <- ufs %>% 
  filter(!code_muni %in% apagar)

ggplot(ufs_sem_muns, aes(group = name_muni)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vamos criar um conjunto de dados "originais" que não tenham esses 40 municípios.

```
dados <- tibble(code_muni = ufs_sem_muns$code_muni) %>% 
  mutate(valor = rnorm(length(code_muni), 100, 10))
head(dados)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   code_muni valor
#>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   1100015  89.3
#> 2   1100023  97.8
#> 3   1100049  89.7
#> 4   1100056  92.7
#> 5   1100072  93.7
#> 6   1100080  83.1
```

E vejamos o que ocorre quando tentamos criar um mapa do resultado do `left_join` desse conjunto de dados com os *shapes* municipais.

```
final <- left_join(dados, ufs, "code_muni")
ggplot(final, aes(geometry = geom)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como seria a forma de resolver então? A forma seria fazer um `full_join` ou `right_join` ou inverter a ordem das tabelas no *join*. Vou adicionar cores no mapa para ficar mais fácil de notar aqueles sem dados (e que desapareciam nos mapas anteriores).

```
final2 <- left_join(ufs, dados, "code_muni")

ggplot(final2, aes(geometry = geom)) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = valor)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]